# Referências não ficam disponíveis no programa final

Tags: python, rest, biblioteca

Estou validando algumas funções criadas em python, tenho um código que cria algumas funções. Ao executar o programa com as funções (test_client.py), recebo erro de execução.
auth_utils.py:

```
from hashlib import sha256
try:
    from urllib import urlencode
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode


def create_signature(secret_key, data=None):
    if data is None:
        data = {}
    url_encoded_data = urlencode(sorted(data.items()))
    hashed_data = sha256(secret_key + url_encoded_data)
    return hashed_data.hexdigest()
```

test_client.py:

```
from auth_utils import create_signature
from time import time


API_KEY = "kaakAYJ58EouuGW2"
API_SECRET = "HRN4Ig7BMB8xY9qVLJA7Ylzy"
DATA = {
    'first_name': 'Jonh',
```

erro na execução:

> $ python test_headers.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "test_headers.py", line 13, in 
>       header = "Authorization Voxy {}:{}".format(API_KEY, create_signature(API_SECRET, DATA))   File
>   "F:\xampp\htdocs\proj\voxy\auth_utils.py", line 12, in
>   create_signature
>       hashed_data = sha256(secret_key + url_encoded_data) TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: Só não compreendi o título da pergunta: o que quis dizer com "referências não ficam disponíveis no programa final"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo erro, está apenas faltando a codificação dos objetos quando for executar o *hash*. Tente aplicar a codificação, tal como:

```
sha256(str(secret_key + url_encoded_data).encode('utf-8'))
```

Ficando:

```
def create_signature(secret_key, data=None):
    if data is None:
        data = {}
    url_encoded_data = urlencode(sorted(data.items()))
    hashed_data = sha256(str(secret_key + url_encoded_data).encode('utf-8'))
    return hashed_data.hexdigest()
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/FpBs/0).

Comment: Valeu Anderson, muito obrigado

Comment: Fiz a alteração, ainda não está executando o create_signature() na função de teste.

Comment: Com o mesmo erro?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_headers.py", line 14, in <module>
    header = "Authorization Voxy {}:{}".format(API_KEY, create_signature(API_SECRET, DATA))
NameError: name 'create_signature' is not defined

Comment: lá Repl.it funcionou

Comment: Se desejar, pode editar sua pergunta adicionando o código do arquivo `test_headers.py`. Aparentemente você não está importando a função para o contexto corretamente.